# Как отловить пустой ответ от MSSQL?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

Помогите отловить пустой ответ от MSSQL
После подключения к базе, делается следующий запрос:

```
$SqlCmd1 = $SqlConnection.CreateCommand()
$SqlCmd1.CommandText = "SELECT ID, CreatedOn, BLA-BLA, BLA-BLA-BLA, ONE, TWO FROM [SOME_DB].[dbo].[SOME_TABLE] where BLA-BLA = $bla-bla and ONE = 'UNKNOWN'"
$objReader = $SqlCmd1.ExecuteReader()

while ($objReader.read()) {
$field1 = $objReader.GetValue(0)
$field2 = $objReader.GetValue(1)
$field3 = $objReader.GetValue(2)
$field4 = $objReader.GetValue(3)
$field5 = $objReader.GetValue(4)
$field6 = $objReader.GetValue(5)

  Echo 'BAD STORY IS
  '  $field5 '

  '
}
$objReader.close()
```

И проблема в том, что если ответ от базы не пустой, то в $field5 есть значение. Но если от базы приходит пустой ответ, то скрипт выдает ошибку.

Какая переменная в данном случае должна иметь значение $null или быть пустой '', чтобы ее можно было отловить через IF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

проверьте на наличие данных:

```
if ($objReader.HasRows)
{
while ...
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! помогло

Comment: А разве первый вызов `$objReader.read()` не вернет `false` если данных нет?